# Performance logging tips

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, performance, logging, windows-services

I am developing large data collecting ASP.Net/Windows service application-pair that uses Microsoft SQL Server 2005 through LINQ2Sql.
Performance is always the issue.

Currently the application is divided into multiple larger processing parts, each logging the duration of their work. This is not detailed and does not help us with anything. It would be nice to have some database tables that contain statistics that the application itself collected from its own behavior.

What logging tips and data structures do you recommend to spot the parts that cause performance problems?

Edit:
Mostly I am looking for parts of the application that can cripple the whole system when excessively used. There are peaks during the day when some parts of the application are under heavy load. Some advanced logging would help me isolate the parts that need more attention and optimizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use logging for this, use Performance Counters instead. The runtime impact of performance counters is minor and you can simple have them always on. To collect and monitor the performance, you can rely on the existing performance counters infrastructure ([perfmon.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404355.aspx), [logman.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303133), [relog.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303133) etc).

I personally use [XML and XSLT to generate the counters](http://rusanu.com/2009/04/11/using-xslt-to-generate-performance-counters-code/). I can then decorate all my code with performance counters tracking functions being run, average call duration time, number of executions, rate of executions per second and so on and so forth. Good choice of counters will give an immediate, accurate, performance picture much faster than logging can. While logging can give more insight on certain event paths (ie. order of events that lead to certain state), logging can seldom be 'always on' as the impact on performance is significant, not only on performance but most importantly on concurrency as most existing logging infrastructures add contention.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a job for logging. It's a job for a profiler.

Try one of these:

- JetBrains' dotTrace - http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html
- Red-Gate ANTS - http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_profiler/index.htm
- Automated QA's AQTime - http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqtime/index.asp

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't (yet) tried it for myself, it may be worth looking at [Gibraltar](http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com/) which can be used with [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/download) to put declarative performance logging into your code.

Comment: You might also want to look into SmartInspect for this (also supports PostSharp), as it supports high-resolution timers.

Comment: In addition to the high-resolution declarative performance logging Jon mentioned, Loupe (formerly Gibraltar) automatically collects dozens of useful performance counters with negligible performance impact and integrates with ASP.NET Health Monitoring for your website as well supporting logging and performance monitoring for your Windows Service.

Best of all, Loupe Desktop (formerly Gibraltar Analyst) is now FREE.  More details on our blog:
http://rocksolid.gibraltarsoftware.com/announcements/our-best-log-viewer-is-now-free

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server keeps track of some things for you, so try running some of these queries on your system:

[Wayback Machine: Uncover Hidden Data to Optimize Application Performance](https://web.archive.org/web/20081230235725/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/magazine/cc135978.aspx)

here is an example from the link:

```
--Identifying Most Costly Queries by I/O 
SELECT TOP 10 
 [Average IO] = (total_logical_reads + total_logical_writes) / qs.execution_count
,[Total IO] = (total_logical_reads + total_logical_writes)
,[Execution count] = qs.execution_count
,[Individual Query] = SUBSTRING (qt.text,qs.statement_start_offset/2, 
         (CASE WHEN qs.statement_end_offset = -1 
            THEN LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), qt.text)) * 2 
          ELSE qs.statement_end_offset END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2) 
        ,[Parent Query] = qt.text
,DatabaseName = DB_NAME(qt.dbid)
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) as qt
ORDER BY [Average IO] DESC;
```

the link contains many queries including ones for: Costly Missing Indexes, Logically Fragmented Indexes, Identifying Queries that Execute Most Often , etc...

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with problems like this I try and not add any extra headache by manually adding logging / tracing & timing into the application itself. If all you want is to tune the application then I suggest getting a profiler which will show you what areas of code are an issue. I recommend [Red-Gate's](http://www.red-gate.com/) [Ant's Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm).

Now if you want to collect statistics for monitoring or trending purposes then a profiler is not the right tool. I have had success using PerformanceCounters which let's many third party tools pull the performance information out of the application.

So what are you trying to do solve performance problems or monitor to ensure you catch a performance problem before it becomes severe?

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, I would look at using performance monitors around critical sections of code, timing how long it took to complete an operation. Then you can use the built in performance monitoring tools, or any number of third party tools to monitor and trend the stats.

Comment: I am trying to identify performance problems. When I am testing the application it performs well but it sometimes starts hogging resources, producing timeouts usually when I am not there. So I need to know from the logs which part of the app peaked and when.

Answer (score 0):

I would start would diagnosing what is the real cause for the perf issue? Is it CPU, Memory, Disk or IO. This can be identified by few perfmon counters.

For example Linq2SQL uses Sync I/O which could be a big bottleneck for scalability. Because it uses Sync I/O windows threads get blocked and requests would end up waiting. This is usual suspect and might not be true. Here is an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx) how sync I/O could affect scalability.

If CPU is an issue then the next question is application CPU bound? Then you could use one of the profilers like mentioned above. Also look for time spent on GC perfmon counter that is another usual suspect?